# Erro ao atualizar o Github, ao dar push na master

Tags: github

Não consigo atualizar a master, nem fazer merge com a master. Consigo subir o projeto em outras branchs, master-b. Mas, ao atualizar a master (dar push) dá esse erro:

OBS: Ao tentar da pull, ocorre esse erro. `git pull origin master`

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

ao tentar subir a master, `git push origin master`

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

E ao fazer o merge, aparece desta forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisa colocar "resolvido" no título. Como a resposta abaixo foi aceita (marcada com ✔️) isso já é o suficiente para indicar que foi resolvido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Acontece que na branch `master` possui itens novos que não foram sincronizados com sua branch `master` local.

Alí no erro ele diz `hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

É só dar `git pull` antes de dar `git push` para ele fazer o merge automático ou pra você arrumar manualmente :)

Comment: Sim, já fiz isso, aí ele dá essa mensagem: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories